# loop within groupby and also change the first row for each group

Tags: python, pandas

i need to find the first row of each group and set a value. then i need to calculate the rest rows based on values from the previous row. I know there are similar answers in stack overflow but i still can't really find the solution for it.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d={'type':['a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b']}
test=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
test = test.groupby('type')

for group,df in test:
    # print(group,df)
    df.loc[0,'value']=800
    for i in range(1,len(df)):
        df.loc[i,'value']=df.loc[i-1,'value']*0.5
```

However, this doesn't return what i want.

```py
type    value
a   800
a   400
a   200
a   100
a   50
b   800
b   400
b   200
b   100
b   50
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible with custom function and `iloc` for select and set by positions, not by index labels:

```
def func(group):
    group.loc[group.index[0],'value']=800
    pos = group.columns.get_loc('value')
    for i in range(1,len(group)):
        group.iloc[i,pos]=group.iloc[i-1,pos]*0.5
    return group

test1 = test.sort_values('type').groupby('type').apply(func)
print (test1)
   type  value
0     a  800.0
2     a  400.0
4     a  200.0
6     a  100.0
8     a   50.0
10    a   25.0
1     b  800.0
3     b  400.0
5     b  200.0
7     b  100.0
9     b   50.0
11    b   25.0
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you please explain why my code doesn't work?

Comment: @Cypress - There is problem you modify subgroup `df` in loop, so changes are not set in original DataFrame, because have its data as a view. Modifying it in place doesn't propagate it back.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Also, i have tried to call the row position with loc function as below and it doesn't work. Can you please help me to understand why? group.loc[i,'value']=group.loc[i-1,'value]*0.5

Comment: @Cypress - Problem is function `loc` select by labels, so it working nice in first group. But in second and next groups first value of group has no index=0, but index=1, second index is not 2, but 3, so need `iloc` for set by position - first, second ... values of groups.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`cumprod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.cumprod.html#pandas.Series.cumprod) after a `groupby` as you always multiply the previous value by 0.5 and then with some adjustment to get the right result such as:

```
d={'type':['a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b']}
test=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
test['value'] = test.assign(value=0.5).groupby('type').cumprod()*800*2
print (test)
   type  value
0     a  800.0
1     b  800.0
2     a  400.0
3     b  400.0
4     a  200.0
5     b  200.0
6     a  100.0
7     b  100.0
8     a   50.0
9     b   50.0
10    a   25.0
11    b   25.0
```

Edit: thanks to [@piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2336654/pirsquared) idea, you can also use [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) per group as the power of 0.5 multiply by the first value 800:

```
test['value'] = 800 * .5 ** test.groupby('type').cumcount()
```

that gives the same result than above

Comment: `test.assign(value=800 * .5 ** test.groupby('type').cumcount())` My answer was too close to yours.  I'm deleting mine in favor of yours.

Comment: @piRSquared I did saw your answer and found it better, I was thinking at `cumcount` but could not find a way of doing it, you are good :)

Comment: That's why I added the comment.  So I can help make your answer better (-:  But you are the one who came up with the insight so I thought it would be better to focus the attention on this answer.  And thank you for the complement.

Comment: @piRSquared Thanks, I added it to my answer as an edit to make a better one then :)

Comment: @Ben.T thanks for your answer. just wonder what does the ** sign mean?

Comment: @Cypress it means power so it is 0.5 power the array created by the `cumcount` method